# very interesting result from latency test of IPC on Linux 2.6.18

Tags: c++, c, linux, performance, low-latency

I am doing a performance (latency) test on unix socket under linux 2.6.18,
a process A writes 1024 bytes to process B on each 10 ms, and the result shows average latency is 20 us with small standard deviation(2~3 us).

The test becomes interesting when I run some additional CPU-bound processes simultaneously with process A&B,  these new process is very cache-friendly such as a busy loop of simple math calculation, but as a result which surprises me, the IPC latency suddenly goes down, become 15 us on average.

As far as I know, to improve interactivity the O(1) scheduler(2.6 prior to 2.6.23) rewards IO-bound process by some heuristic method, but this can't explain why the speed becomes faster even than the first case.

I have also considered that if the Linux do some special case of busy-loop when process A was rewarded, but it seems not by further test.

This really confuses me.

---

my configuration: 
CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2609 0 @ 2.40GHz with 10M L3 cache
MEM: 32G
OS: Linux 2.6.18-308.el5 SMP x86_64

Comment: And what if you use something more current? https://www.kernel.org/finger_banner

Comment: OK, I try test it on more current Linux for comparison.

Comment: I suppose the performance boost comes from some kind of spatial locality,  since the working sets of these process were not so large, so kernel may read/write data 'from DRAM'/'to cache' in one shot.

Comment: Maybe 'Dynamic frequency scaling' is the answer, like Intel® Demand Based Switching: "a power-management technology in which the applied voltage and clock speed of a microprocessor are kept at the minimum necessary levels until more processing power is required. This technology was introduced as Intel SpeedStep® Technology in the server marketplace."

Comment: Run `powertop` and look how much time is spent in power-saving states.

Comment: Probably the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584240/java-blockingqueue-latency-high-on-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that some power-saving feature of the hardware is at work here.  A 10ms sleep is more than enough time for modern hardware to enter a low-power state.  When you're looking at things at the microsecond level, there is a real, measurable latency to come out of a power-saving state.

My guess is that running the "busy" program in parallel prevents the hardware from entering a low power state.  Standard things to try:

- At the BIOS level, disable any and all power-saving features including C-states
- At the OS level, disable cpuspeed (or whatever frequency scaling program your distro uses)
- Try booting with the "idle=poll" kernel parameter

That last suggestion is especially important for Sandy Bridge CPUs (which is what you have),  at least with RHEL/CentOS 5.x (which I'm guessing you're running).  I found the Linux kernel would still override some BIOS settings.  Other Linux kernel params that may help you:

- intel_idle.max_state=0
- processor.max_cstate=0